# Find duplicates in a column, then add values in adjacent column

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pyexcel

I have a csv file that has a one word title and a description that is always a number.
My current code extracts just the title an description to another csv file and then converts the csv into an excel file.

```
import csv  
import output
f = open("Johnny_Test-punch_list.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
m = open('data.csv', "w")
for row in csv_f:
    m.write(row[1])
    m.write(",")
    m.write(row[3])
    m.write("\n")
m.close()
output.toxlsx()
```

How can I look for matching Titles and then add the descriptions of the titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv  
import output
f = open("Johnny_Test-punch_list.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
m = open('data.csv', "w")
dict_out = {}
for row in csv_f:
    if row[1] in dict_out:
        dict_out[row[1]] += row[3]
    else:
        dict_out[row[1]] = row[3]
for title, value in dict_out.iteritems():
    m.write('{},{}\n'.format(title, value))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need to write in a single line as a string.

can you try with below code:

```
for row in csv_f:
    m.write(row[1] + "," + str(row[3]) + "\n")
```

Comment: That formats my csv exactly like I have it now, I would like it to go through the list 
`Siding,50
Siding,63
Siding,22 
Siding,68 
Siding,138 
Siding,47 
Siding,123 
Siding,107 
Siding,107 
Siding,93 
Siding,117 
Grinding,127 
Grinding,47 
Grinding,20 
Grinding,66 
Rail,82 
Rail,98 
Rail,89 
Rail,62 
Rail,58
Asphalt,49 
Asphalt,8 
Asphalt,72
Asphalt,19
Asphalt,125
Asphalt,144
Concrete,130
Concrete,75
Concrete,12
Concrete,88
Concrete,143 
Concrete,16`
and then add totals of concrete, rail, etc...